# Remove the first and the last character of a string using XSLT

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, solr

I would need to transform the response from a Solr server into an XML-like formatting by using stylesheet transformations. A number of fields from the Solr schema are multivalued and include square brackets, which indicate an array. For display purposes, I would like to remove these brackets at the beginning and the end of the field value. Currently, my XSLT looks like this (the example refers to the field title and handles records with no title, too:

```
<pnx:title>
      <xsl:variable name="title">
              <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="string-length(field[@name='title']) &gt; 0">
              <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='title']" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='text']" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:variable>

              <!-- handle empty title -->
              <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="string-length($title) = 0">
              Untitled
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
              </pnx:title>
```

I would normally use substring(string, number, number) to remove characters from a string, but in this case I do not know the position of the last character. Any idea?

Thanks,
I.

Comment: You may simply use string-length() function to get last position like string-length() - 1

Answer (score 6):

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="abc">[11sdf sdsdf sdfds fsdf dsfsdf fsd2]</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($abc)"/>
  <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select=" $length"/></xsl:message>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($abc,2,($length - 2))"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produce output:

```
11sdf sdsdf sdfds fsdf dsfsdf fsd2
```

Comment: thanks indeed for your answer, but it was easier for me to make use of substring-before and substring-after.

Comment: Yes, you can. As you mentioned in your question - you normally use string-length() and you are unable to use it here that's why I choose this method to explain it clearly. But what if you have multiple brackets and you want to remove only brackets (at the beginning and the end of the field value) as you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I have succesfully solved the issue by using `substring-before` and `substring-after`. Please see below:

```
<pnx:title>
    <xsl:variable name="title">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(field[@name='title']) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(field[@name='title'],'['),']')" />
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='text']" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--handle empty title-->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($title) = 0">
            Untitled
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</pnx:title>
```

Thanks,

I.